# Is the "audioplayers" package working for you?

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

I have been doing Flutter for only 2 weeks. I love it. Everything has been going well. Until now.

I need an app I am building to play a few short sounds on certain events. This package seemed the way to go:

https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers

It looks so simple to play a sound, and the package gets a 99% popularity. BUT!

I can't even get the thing to build. I get a bunch of different build errors when I try to use it, even with a dead simple demo app. A bunch of stuff like:

**"Incompatible classes were found in dependencies. Remove them from the classpath or use '-Xskip-metadata-version-check' to suppress errors"**

and

**"Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15."**

This stuff is way over my head. Until yesterday everything "just worked." I have used at least 4 other packages seamlessly. I am frustrated and need help.

Can anyone throw an old dog a bone? :)

Answer (score 1):

In your project folder in android/build.gradle change

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
```

to

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32'
```

Comment: Thanks.  It didn't work.  I still got a wall of errors. The last one was different now, though:

**[!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.
    Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions, then update C:\Users\[myname]\Desktop\flutter_dev\__2022\audio\play_01\android\build.gradle:
    ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'**

Comment: @mattgflutter7 What is your flutter version? This seems to be the error you get if you're on 2.9.0 which is not yet on stable channel: https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/kotlin-version. If that's the case use `1.5.31` instead of `1.4.32` according to documentation.